# How to Deserialize a JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am struggling with a subject that has a lot of variants in this forum but I can't seem to find one that suits me, and I think it's because of the way that my JSON array is :( I'm not an expert but I already manage to "almost" get the end.. I need to get hand in "Status" and "listOfCredDetails" value.

My JSON (is called responseFromServer):

```
 {
 "Status": {
             "StatusCode":143,
             "SubStatus":0,
             "Description":"Ok"
           },
 "ListofCredDetails":
                  [{
                     "Client":"a",
                     "CredID":111,
                     "CredUserID":"abc"
                   },
                   {
                     "Client":"b",
                     "CredID":112,
                     "CredUserID":"def"
                   },
                   {
                     "Client":"c",
                     "CredID":113,
                     "CredUserID":"ghi"
                   }]
  }
```

Then, based on lot of examples in this forum, taking bits and pieces I created my classes:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class StatusReturn
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public int SubStatus { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


 [Serializable]
public class CredDetailsReturn
{
    public string Client{ get; set; }
    public int CredID{ get; set; }
    public string CredUserID{ get; set; }

}

 [Serializable]
public class GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn
{
    public StatusReturn status;
    public List<CredDetailsReturn> listOfCredDetails;

    public GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn()
    {
        status = new StatusReturn();
        listOfCredDetails = new List<CredDetailsReturn>();

    }
}
```

Then Am going to deserialize to get

1."Status" and its elements into one object and

2."ListofCredDetails" and its List of elements into one object

and then creating object for "GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn" to return both status(object) and ListofCredDetails(object) at a time.

Can anyone help me understand how can i achieve this i have tried some like below to deserialize and to get Json data into two seperate objects.

But it is not working....

```
public GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn InvokeRequest(RESTInvokeClass objInvoke)
    {

      ...
      ... 
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            string responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn result = new GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn();
            result.status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusReturn>(responseText);
            result.listOfCredDetails  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CredDetailsReturn>>(responseText);

            return result; 

        }

    }
```

Comment: You should be doing this: `GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn>(responseText)`. And remove the lines `result.status = ...` and `result.listOfCredDetails = ...`

Comment: @ rob... I dont need the complete JSON to deserialize into one Object.. I need "Status" part of data in JSON into one object and "ListofCredDetails"(list) part of data in JSON into another object..

Comment: Usually it is much simpler to deserialize the complete JSON text and just access the elements you need. Otherwise, if you really want some isolated elements only, you need to use the lower level parts of the JSON library: Parse the stream of tokens yourself, keep track of the object tree and return just the elements you need.

Comment: Ty @DrKoch. But, That's the requirement given to me.. They need 2 seperate objects each containing the two different data(explained earlier) and to return those 2 objects by binding those into one single object. Can you give some examples on that... And links to the same will be helpfull.

Comment: did you visit `json2csharp.com`

Comment: Hi, Can someone explain how to populate the result of JSON into array insted of list in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first change your property names in the class    `GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn`as status to Status and listOfCredDetails to ListofCredDetails.

Then you can try to de-serialize your Json into your class `GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn`by the code below.

```
GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn result = new GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn();
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn>(responseText);
```

You can get your status and listOfCredDetails with in the result.

```
   // result.Status
   // result.ListofCredDetails
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Serializable]
public class GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn
{
    public StatusReturn status { get; set; }
    public List<CredDetailsReturn> listOfCredDetails { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.Deserialize<GetUserCredentialDetailsReturn>(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just some isolated elements of a (say very large) JSON File you need the lower level parts of the JSON Library, for example from Newtonsoft:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Then create a parser which reads through the JSON Tokens:

```
var reader = new JsonTextReader(...);
```

You'll get token by token:

```
    private void nextToken()
    {
        do
        {
            if (!reader.Read()) this.importError("unexpected end of file");
        }
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment);
    }
```

and have to handle this in a Token Parser. For example if you read an array:

```
    private void readMyArray()
    {
        // StartArray
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray) this.importError("expected start of array '['");
        this.nextToken();

        while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            this.readMyElement();
        }            
        // EndArray
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray) this.importError("expected end of array ']'");
        this.nextToken();
    }
```

This technique is explained in every book about building compilers.